# SOAP request and "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: node.js, ssl, soap, soap-client

I have a PFX file. I generated PEM and KEY file:

- `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys`
- `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.key -nocerts -nodes`

I imported them like this:

```
soap.createClient( url, {wsdl_options: {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.key')

},  wsdl_headers: {Authorization: auth}}, function(err, client) {

    if(err) throw err;

    client.describe();

});
```

But nodemon throw me this error:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1060:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:584:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
```

I guess i did something wrong with openssl certifacte generator.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use self signed certificate and trying to call a remote resource, try to add `rejectUnauthorized: false` to `wsdl_options`. This helps you to test the SOAP service and can replace with intended certificate in production.